# HREF setando cor do botão

Tags: html, button

Eu tenho um `fa-icon` básico e quero aplicar um link nele para redirecionar ao facebook.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porém quando adicionei a propriedade `href`, ele alterou a cor do botão deixando azul, como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

meu código:

```
<div>
    <div class="text-center">
     <a class="btn" href="https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Eu quero manter ele branco como padrão e inserir o link. Como posso resolver?

Comment: Vc está usando bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

O ícone ficou azul por ser um link já visitado. Para manter o botão branco, basta forçar o estilo de links visitados em um arquivo css ou na tag `<style>` no próprio html:

```
a:visited {
    color: white;
}
```